# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism PLAIN not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, smtp, sendmail

I am trying to send emails from my website by using aplus.net
I am getting this error
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (504 5.3.3 AUTH mechanism PLAIN not available

Here is my configiration

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "mail.aplus.net",
      :port => 1025,
      :domain => 'www.limoexotic.com',
      :user_name => 'booking@limoexotic.com',
      :password => 'xxxx',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true 
  }
```

Comment: Probably you need to try with `:enable_starttls_auto => false`.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you should check with `telnet` to see which authentication mechanisms are available by the mail server. In this case, `mail.aplus.net` only allows `LOGIN` authentication (See `AUTH LOGIN` below), so changing `:plain` to `:login` should make it work.

```sh
> $ telnet mail.aplus.net 1025
Trying 64.29.151.235...
Connected to mail.aplus.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail42c40.carrierzone.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.9/8.14.9; Tue, 7 Jul 2020 05:04:56 +0000
EHLO mail.aplus.net
250-mail42c40.carrierzone.com Hello [x.x.x.x], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 52428800
250-DSN
250-AUTH LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

Comment: AUTH LOGIN sends password unencrypted.  It **SHOULD** be used after `STARTTLS` (turning on encryption).